# Zombie Views in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

**JS Console errors:**

Uncaught ViewDestroyedError: View (cid: "view351") has already been destroyed and cannot be used. backbone.marionette.js?body=1:1715

**Code:**

```
initialize: (options) ->
  HWAs = @model.get('homework_assignments')
  @collection = new App.Collections.HomeworkAssignments(HWAs)
  @collection.on "sync", =>
    @render()
  @collection.fetch()
```

I get zombie views if I do this:

1. Open the page that uses the above code
2. Click the browser's back button
3. Click on the link to the view that uses the above code

Any idea why this might be happening??

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much code to work with, but here's my best guess.

You are binding your collection to this view class every time you instantiate a view of this class.

```
@collection.on "sync", =>
    @render()
```

When a view of this class gets destroyed, however, it's not cleaning up the binding to `@collection`, because the binding is on the `collection`, rather than the `view`. So now every time you sync the collection, it tries to call refresh on every instance of this view you've created and bound to the collection since the last page reload, some of which are apparently dead.  They're probably dead because you re-rendered a parent, or a region, or something else that's containing them, but without more code I'm not 100% certain what's going on.

The best solution is probably to include a cleanup function in your view.

```
onBeforeClose: () ->
    @collection.off("sync", @render())
```

You may also need to change your sync function to the following syntax:

```
@collection.on("sync", @render())
```

I'm not sure if backbone will recognize an anonymous function that calls `@render()` as synonymous with the `@render()` function itself.  Either way, your anonymous function calling the `@render()` function just serves to introduce unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I think that your diagnosis of the problem is correct, but none of your suggestions worked. I also tried the syntax `@listenTo(@collection, 'sync', @render)` without success

Comment: @Phil - maybe make a jsFiddle?

Comment: unfortunately there are a lot of moving parts in the whole Marionette app. probably it's just best to troubleshoot on my own. thank you again for all your help!